# PHP script doesn't wait for Ajax and jQuery document.ready

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, element

I'm new to PHP and Ajax. I am working on a dynamic website for personal use which requires the website to respond to the window width of the client.

At the moment this is set up to send the width through an Ajax GET request and just print the size back to the screen, although this PHP script will print a response before the page gets to load, leaving a static 'width < 1275' at the top of the page which will never be removed.

How would I go about solving this issue? Thanks

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="contents">

    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var width = $(window).width();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions.php', 
        type: 'GET', 
        data: {size : width},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#contents').html(response);
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions.php', 
            type: 'GET', 
            data: {size : width},
            success: function(response) {
                $('#contents').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $width = $_GET['size'] ?? '';

    if($width < 1275)
    {
        echo('<div class="column">' . 'width < 1275' . '</div>');
    }
    else
    {
        echo('<div class="column">' . 'width > 1275' . '</div>');
    }
?>
```

Comment: by making your ajax, synchronous

Comment: Here's a screenshot if I cant explain my problem
https://imgur.com/kHAWMJq

Comment: add async: false inside ajax call

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you sending this to PHP at all? Why not just do it in JS directly?

Comment: Theres a number of things I want printed to the page dependant on the screen size, and I'd like to order them prior to the client receiving them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your js code is just fine. 1s make sure you have jquery,
here is the CDN: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js ,
Then change `<div class="contents">`  to `<div id="contents">` 
because `$('#contents').html(response);`  '#' is for id selector & '.' for class so `$('.contents').html(response);` will be the code if you want to use class for DOM. 
and in php part functions.php do something like this :

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_GET['size'] )){
            $width = $_GET['size'] ;

    if($width < 1275)
    {
        echo('<div class="column">' . 'width < 1275' . '</div>');
    }
    else
    {
        echo('<div class="column">' . 'width > 1275' . '</div>');
    }


    }
    else{

        echo " nothing found";
    }

?>
```

and here is my index page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
    <div id="contents">

    </div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var width = $(window).width();
    resize(width);


    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        resize(width);
    });



       function resize(width){

        $.ajax({
        url: 'functions.php', 
        type: 'GET',

        data: {size : width},
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#contents').html(response);
        }
    });

    }
});




</script>
```

Comment: My bad that should have been id="content" from the beginning, after trying what you've left it now prints 'nothing found' at the top of the page with the correct functionality underneath https://imgur.com/a/1FOxGLL

Comment: its showing because , size variable that you are passing via ajax has no value in it ,simply means  data: {size : width},   here variable 'width' has no value , put a 'console.log(width)' inside  '$(window).resize()'  function and check if you are getting value in width via browser console.

Comment: i have updated my answer with full code , working on my end..

Comment: Thankyou, I checked the files you suggested with success. After implementing into my own project I received a 'nothing found' above all the other elements so I have just commented that echo out and everything runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try your AJAX code with `async: false` like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var width = $(window).width();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions.php', 
        type: 'GET', 
        async: false,
        data: {size : width},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#contents').html(response);
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions.php', 
            type: 'GET', 
            async: false,
            data: {size : width},
            success: function(response) {
                $('#contents').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: No such luck sadly

Comment: In Ajax success response you used the same div id '#contents' so it overrides the first result with the second one. so try with another div id.

Comment: The problem is a premature print of the 'width < 1275' to the top of the page, will this remove that top printed text? https://imgur.com/kHAWMJq

Comment: Try with using $_POST in php side and use type POST method in ajax.